# Getting data from datatable then passing it to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables, I can get data from selected row using this code

```
var str = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[5]+" "+item[0]
                });
```

where `item[5]` is id, `item[0]` is a string.

I want to split return string for passing id and string.
the error founded in ajax code specifically in

```
data : {}
```

where is the problem in this code.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#liveSearch').DataTable();
    $('#liveSearch tbody').off('click', 'tr').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

        $('.example3-1').on('click', function () {
            if ((table.rows('.selected').data().length) > 0) {
                var str = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[5]+" "+item[0]
                });
                console.log(str);
            $.confirm({
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn-info',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
                confirm: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        data: {
                            str1 : str.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')),
                            str2 : str.substr(str.indexOf(' ')+1)
                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            console.log( data );
                        }
                    });
                    table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);

                }
            });
        }
        });
} );
```

Comment: Have you tried using the javascript debugger in the browser?

Comment: No **Use the javascript debugger** its a great tool and lives in all browsers. Try F12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You're only allowing only one row selected. But you're using [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) which returns `Array` not a `string` as you expect. There is no sense in using [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) for just one row.

> **SOLUTION**

Use the following code instead to get data for selected row and produce the string needed.

```js
var rowdata = table.row('.selected').data();
var str = rowdata[5] + " " + rowdata[0];
```

It could be simplified further:

```js
var rowdata = table.row('.selected').data();

// ... skipped ...

$.ajax({

   // ... skipped ...

   data: {
      str1: rowdata[5],
      str2: rowdata[0]
   }

   // ... skipped ...
```

});

> **NOTES**

The solution would be different if you allow multiple row selection.